# How to get the type of a std::function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, std-function

I'm trying to store callbacks for events in a map. Since there should be one callback per class i'm currently using `typeid(<eventClass>).name()` as key and the std::function as value. The problem i'm having is when registering the callback, i need the type of the event, and the only possible solution i came up with was passing the event class as template argument. This is a working example that i would like to "optimize":

```cpp
std::map<Widget *, std::map<std::string, std::function<void(Widget*, Event &)>>> handlers;

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Event, T>, bool> = true>
void setCallback(Widget *obj, const std::function<void(Widget *, T &event)> &callback) {
    handlers[obj].insert(std::make_pair(typeid(T).name(), reinterpret_cast<const std::function<void(Widget *, Event &)> &>(callback)));
}

void fire(Widget *obj, Event &event) {
    auto it = handlers.find(obj);
    if (it != handlers.end()) {
        auto it2 = it->second.find(typeid(event).name());
        if (it2 != it->second.end()) {
            it2->second(obj, event);
            return; // debug
        }
    }

    printf("No handler found!\n"); // debug
}
```

Because of the template arguments in the `setCallback` function, using the method looks like this:

```cpp
void callback(Widget *, BarEvent &barEvent) {
    printf("%d\n", barEvent.getFoo());
}

void callback2(Widget *, FooEvent &fooEvent) {
    printf("%d\n", fooEvent.getFoo());
}

int main() {

    Widget *obj = new Widget();
    Widget *obj2 = new Widget();
    setCallback<BarEvent>(obj, callback);
    setCallback<FooEvent>(obj2, callback2);

    BarEvent event;
    fire(obj, event);
    fire(obj2, event);

    FooEvent event2;
    fire(obj, event2);
    fire(obj2, event2);

    delete obj;
    delete obj2;
    return 0;
}
```

Having to pass the template parameter when setting a callback is error prone and just "overhead", because the event class is already in the callback. Is there a way to get the type of the second argument of the `callback` parameter in the `setCallback` function?

If it's possible, the function should look something like this:

```cpp
void setCallback(Widget *widget, const std::function<void(Widget *, Event &)> &callback) {
    handlers[widget].insert(std::make_pair(typeid(<2nd param of callback>).name(), callback));
}
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not your friend. If I were you I would ask how to get rid of it, not how to wrap in it in a shiny package.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Since the callback now actually has a reference to an event as second parameter instead of "T" the reinterpret_cast wouldn't be necessary anymore

Comment: So how is `setCallback` supposed to divine out the type if everything is a `std::function<void(Widget *, Event &)>`?

Comment: If the actually passed argument would be `std::function<void(Widget*, FooEvent &>`, wouldn't typeid still work because it's evaluated at runtime time?

Comment: But then how are you planning to go from `std::function<void(Widget*, FooEvent &)>` fo `std::function<void(Widget*, Event &)>`?

Comment: Since FooEvent is an extension of Event, i can just pass it wherever `Event` is used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240316/discussion-between-masy-and-n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m).

Comment: Inheritance doesn't work this way. `std::function<void(Widget*, FooEvent &)>` and `std::function<void(Widget*, Event &)>` are unrelated incompatible types, regardless of whatever relationship may exist between `Event` and `FooEvent`. Why were you using `reinterpret_cast` in the first place if not for this reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that doesn't use `reinterpret_cast` and does deduction automatically (in many but not all cases). The code is complete and runnable, but interrupted with plain text (more readable than monospace comments).

```
  #include <vector>
  #include <map>
  #include <typeinfo>
  #include <typeindex>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <type_traits>
  
  struct Event
  {
      virtual ~Event() = default;
  };
  
  struct FooEvent : Event {};
  struct BarEvent : Event {};
  
  template <typename>
  struct extract_second_argument;
```

The next section is our plumbing for extraction of the second argument type from plain functions and `std::function` objects. Note that these are not all things that can be called. The mechanism doesn't work with lambdas and other function objects, or pointers to members.

```
  template <typename A, typename B, typename C, typename ... X>
  struct extract_second_argument<A (*)(B, C, X...)>
  {
      using type = std::remove_reference_t<C>;
  };
  
  template <typename A, typename B, typename C, typename ... X>
  struct extract_second_argument<std::function<A(B, C, X...)>>
  {
      using type = std::remove_reference_t<C>;
  };
  
  template <typename T>
  using extract_second_argument_t = typename extract_second_argument<T>::type;
```

This is our (simplified) Widget. It contains not one, but two different callback containers! Choose the one that you like. Note the plain vector one may be preferred even though it is slower (does more dynamic casts) because it, unlike the map-based one, supports hierarchies of callbacks. You can add a callback for a Parent event and for a Child event, and if Child is fired, both callbacks will be called. Whether you need this or not is your call. Both mechanisms allow for many callbacks per event type (this is desirable in most cases, but if it's not your cup of tea, just use a plain map instead of a multimap).

```
  struct Widget {
      using Callback = std::function<void(Widget&, Event&)>;
      using CallbackList = std::vector<Callback>;
      using CallbackMap = std::multimap<std::type_index, Callback>;
  
      CallbackList callbacks;
      CallbackMap callbacks2;
```

This adds a callback of any nature (plain function, `std::function`, lambda...) but no argument type deduction.

```
      template <typename EV>
      void addCallbackImpl(std::function<void(Widget&, EV&)> cb)
      {
```

This wrapper is the heart of the machine. Note that it uses the polymorphic nature of `Event`.

```
          auto wrapper = [=](Widget& w, Event& ev) {
              auto* realEv = dynamic_cast<EV*>(&ev);
              if (realEv) cb(w, *realEv);
          };
```

Our two callback containers (you only need one).

```
          callbacks.push_back(wrapper);
          callbacks2.insert({std::type_index(typeid(EV)), wrapper});
      }
```

This will try and add a callback that is either a plain function pointer or a `std::function`. It will not work with lambdas, but will do argument type deduction.

```
      template <typename F>
      void addCallback(F cb)
      {
          addCallbackImpl<extract_second_argument_t<F>>(cb);
      };
```

Call callbacks in both kinds of containers.

```
      void fire (Event& ev)
      {
          std::cout << "callbacks with method 1\n";
          for (auto& cb: callbacks) cb(*this, ev);
  
          std::cout << "callbacks with method 2\n";
          auto range = callbacks2.equal_range(std::type_index(typeid(ev)));
          for (auto& cb = range.first; cb != range.second; ++cb) cb->second(*this, ev);
      }
  };
```

Now the test driver.

```
  void cb1 (Widget&, FooEvent&)
  {   
      std::cout << "cb1 called\n";
  }
  
  void cb2 (Widget&, BarEvent&)
  {
      std::cout << "cb2 called\n";
  }
  
  int main()
  {
      Widget w;
  
      w.addCallback(cb1);
      w.addCallback(cb2);
  
      FooEvent foo;
      BarEvent bar;
      w.fire(foo);
      w.fire(bar);
  }
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1sEWaenq4)

**Update** It should be possible to extract the argument type from a lambda, but I cannot vouch for portability of this method.

Add this specialisation for `extract_second_argument`:

```
  template <typename T>
  struct extract_second_argument
  {
      template <typename P, typename A, typename B, typename C, typename ... X>
      static C& extract_second_argument_from_memfun(A (P::* op)(B, C, X...) const);

      template <typename P, typename A, typename B, typename C, typename ... X>
      static C& extract_second_argument_from_memfun(A (P::* op)(B, C, X...));

      using type = std::remove_reference_t
        <decltype(extract_second_argument_from_memfun(&T::operator()))>;
  };
```

Comment: Is there any way to get it to work with lambdas as well? If not, it's still a good solution.

Comment: It should be possible to get the argument from a lambda (but obviously not from a generic lambda), will update the answer shortly.

Comment: generic ones aren't necessary, the update works just fine for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

Updated example that allows for only one callback per event, without typecasting or rtti.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Event
{
};

struct FooEvent : public Event {};
struct BarEvent : public Event {};

class Widget 
{
public:
    // use a function pointer for automatic template deduction
    // todo add specialization for member functions of classes
    template<typename event_t>
    void set_callback(void (*fn)(Widget&, event_t))
    {
        // static asserts tend to give more readable error messages then SFINAE (std::enable_if_t)
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Event, event_t>, "not a valid event type");

        // get the callback map for this for this event type.
        // basically there is one static map for each event_t
        // and event registrations are done based on the widget instance id (m_id)
        auto& callback_map = get_callback_map<event_t>();

        // set the callback for this instance of the widget to the passed function
        callback_map[m_id] = std::function{ fn };
    }

    // select an event firing implementation based on the even type
    template<typename event_t>
    void fire_event(const event_t& ev)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Event, event_t>, "not a valid event type");

        // again get the callback map
        auto& callback_map = get_callback_map<event_t>();
        auto it = callback_map.find(m_id);
        if (it == callback_map.end()) return;

        auto callback = it->second;
        callback(*this, ev);
    }

private:
    // static function for generating member id's
    static std::size_t get_id()
    {
        static std::size_t id{ 0 };
        return ++id;
    }

    // get the singleton handler map for event_t
    template<typename event_t>
    static auto& get_callback_map()
    {
        static std::unordered_map<std::size_t,std::function<void(Widget&, event_t)>> callback_map;
        return callback_map;
    }

    // the widget's instance id
    std::size_t m_id{ get_id() };
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void foo_callback(Widget& widget, FooEvent foo_event)
{
    std::cout << "FooEvent\n";
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void bar_callback(Widget& widget, BarEvent bar_event)
{
    std::cout << "BarEvent\n";
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    Widget w1;
    Widget w2;
    FooEvent foo_event;
    BarEvent bar_event;

    // register handlers
    w1.set_callback(foo_callback);
    w2.set_callback(bar_callback);

    // show reactions to events
    // w1 will react to foo_event but not to bar_event
    std::cout << "w1 reactions : \n";
    w1.fire_event(foo_event);
    w1.fire_event(bar_event);
    
    std::cout << "w2 reactions : \n";
    w2.fire_event(foo_event);
    w2.fire_event(bar_event);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, this would mean that one widget could only have one callback, but i want the widget to be able to have one callback for each event

Comment: Updated the example to have one handler per event type

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question. If it is about getting the type of one of the arguments of a `std::function` you can use partial specialization of a template. Partial specialization doesn't work with function templates, so we need to use a helper type:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Widget {};
struct Event {
    static void sayHello(){ std::cout << "hello\n";}
};

template <typename F> struct event_from_function;

template <typename EVENT>
struct event_from_function< std::function<void(Widget*,EVENT&)>> {
    using type = EVENT;
};

template <typename F>
void foo(F f) {
    event_from_function<F>::type::sayHello();
}

int main() {
    std::function<void(Widget*,Event&)> f;
    foo(f);    
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KP7PMKj11).

`sayHello` and `foo` is just an example to get some output by getting the argument type (`Event`) from `T` (which is `std::function<void(Widget*,Event&>`).